# How to handle exception during creation?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I am trying to test actor, that is using [Akka Typed Persistence](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html). The scenario is, the database is offline and it should send a notification to another actor, that the database is not available.

During the creation of child actor, that will persist the data to the database, it throws the following error:

```
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://StoreTestOffline/user/OfflineStoreActor/StoreChilid: exception during creation
        at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:202)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:696)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:547)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:569)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:293)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:228)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default journal plugin is not configured, see 'reference.conf'
        at akka.persistence.Persistence$.verifyPluginConfigIsDefined(Persistence.scala:193)
        at akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedSettings$.defaultJournalPluginId$1(EventSourcedSettings.scala:57)
        at akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedSettings$.journalConfigFor(EventSourcedSettings.scala:61)
        at akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedSettings$.apply(EventSourcedSettings.scala:39)
        at akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedSettings$.apply(EventSourcedSettings.scala:22)
        at akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedBehaviorImpl.apply(EventSourcedBehaviorImpl.scala:83)
        at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.start(Behavior.scala:331)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl$$anon$1.start(InterceptorImpl.scala:45)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.AbstractSupervisor.aroundStart(Supervision.scala:72)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl.preStart(InterceptorImpl.scala:68)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl$.$anonfun$apply$1(InterceptorImpl.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$DeferredBehavior$$anon$1.apply(Behavior.scala:264)
        at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.start(Behavior.scala:331)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.preStart(ActorAdapter.scala:238)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:550)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart$(Actor.scala:550)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.aroundPreStart(ActorAdapter.scala:51)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:676)
        ... 9 more

[ERROR] [08/30/2019 12:28:15.391] [StoreTestOffline-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://StoreTestOffline/user] death pact with Actor[akka://StoreTestOffline/user/OfflineStoreActor/StoreChilid#-1253371311] was triggered
akka.actor.typed.DeathPactException: death pact with Actor[akka://StoreTestOffline/user/OfflineStoreActor/StoreChilid#-1253371311] was triggered
        at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretSignal(Behavior.scala:402)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.handleSignal(ActorAdapter.scala:128)
        at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.aroundReceive(ActorAdapter.scala:87)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch.$anonfun$receivedTerminated$1(DeathWatch.scala:67)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch.$anonfun$receivedTerminated$1$adapted(DeathWatch.scala:65)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:438)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch.receivedTerminated(DeathWatch.scala:65)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch.receivedTerminated$(DeathWatch.scala:64)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receivedTerminated(ActorCell.scala:447)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.autoReceiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:597)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The way, how I spawn the child is:

```
object MessageSupervisorSpec {

  def create(communicator: Option[ActorRef[RpcCmd]], logger: Option[ActorRef[LogCmd]]): Behavior[MessageCmd] =

    Behaviors.setup { context =>

        context.log.info("=============> Start MessageSupervisorSpec <=============")

        val fault = Behaviors
            .supervise(Persistence.create(communicator, logger))
            .onFailure[ActorInitializationException](SupervisorStrategy.stop)

        val store = context.spawn(fault, "StoreChilid")

        context.watch(store)

        def loop(): Behavior[MessageCmd] =
            Behaviors.receiveMessage {
            case SaveMessage(v) =>
                println(v)
                store ! SaveMessage(v)
                Behavior.same
            }


        loop()

    }   
}
```

The code of the child actor:

```
object Persistence {


  val storeName = "connector-store"

  /*
   * Persist all incoming messages from KAFKA or SAP
   */

  private val commandHandler: Option[ActorRef[RpcCmd]] => (MessageState, MessageCmd) => Effect[MessageEvent, MessageState]
  = communicator => { (_, command) =>
    command match {
      case SaveMessage(data) =>
        Effect
          .persist(MessageSaved(data))
          .thenRun(state => communicator.foreach(actor => actor ! SendMessage(state.value)))
    }
  }

  private val eventHandler: (MessageState, MessageEvent) => MessageState
  = { (_, event) =>
    event match {
      case MessageSaved(data) => MessageState(data)
    }
  }

  def create(communicator: Option[ActorRef[RpcCmd]], logger: Option[ActorRef[LogCmd]]): Behavior[MessageCmd] =

    Behaviors.setup { context =>

      context.log.info("=============> Start PersistenceMessageActor <=============")

      EventSourcedBehavior[MessageCmd, MessageEvent, MessageState](
        persistenceId = PersistenceId(storeName),
        emptyState = MessageState(),
        commandHandler = commandHandler(communicator),
        eventHandler = eventHandler)
        .onPersistFailure(SupervisorStrategy.restartWithBackoff(minBackoff = 10.seconds, maxBackoff = 60.seconds, randomFactor = 0.1))
        .receiveSignal {
          case (_, _) =>
            println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
            context.log.error("PersistenceMessageActor has been terminated. Please check the persistence.")
            logger.foreach(actor => actor ! SaveLog(Log(Error, "Message store actor was stopped!")))
        }

    }

}
```

I expect to receive a `Signal` that I can handle accordingly but I did not get anyone.

The question is, how to handle the case, when the actor can not be started, to receive the signal.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the config is missing akka.persistence.journal.plugin in application.conf
where you want to store the journal for the persistent actor.